# How to check if relationship model's fields are empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, relationship, has-one

I have a *user* and user *details* models that are in *has-one* <-> *belong-to* relationship. Initially, when the user is registered (created) his *details* are not populated.

I want when the user log in, if his  *details* are not populated to show a *details* form and "force" him to complete his profile.

So, in the application controller I have added the following code:

```
  before_filter :is_profile_complete

  helper_method :current_user

  private

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= SecurityUser.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    end

    def is_profile_complete
      if current_user
        unless current_user.is_profile_completed
           redirect_to security_users_detail_path
        end
      end
    end
```

So, generally, if the user is log in, the is_profile_complete method will call is_profile_complete model method, which looks that:

```
  def is_profile_completed
    is_completed = true
    self.security_users_detail.attributes.each do |field_name, field_value|
      if field_value.blank? || field_value.empty?
        is_completed = false
        break
      end
    end
    is_completed
  end
```

So, I want to check if any of the *details* fields is empty - if it is, the profile is not completed.

Unfortunately, the model method above generates the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /
>
> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703,
>   SQLERRMC=SECURITY_USERS_DETAILS.SECURITY_USER_ID, DRIVER=3.65.77:
>   SELECT  security_users_details.* FROM security_users_details  WHERE
>   security_users_details.security_user_id = 301 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY

As far as I have try to debug this, the issue is caused by this statement:

```
self.security_users_detail.attributes
```

Has anyone idea why this could happen?

**EDIT:**

The screen shot below the *details* table field:

[image]

and as you can see there is no column referencing *users* table. Could be this causing the issue and does this mean that if I am using any associations I always should created additional columns for the reference?

Comment: Do you have pending migrations that needs to be run? It seems like either the `security_user_id` column or the `security_users_details` table does not exist.

Comment: try running the query directly on your database to find out what is invalid.

Comment: @Domon, No I have not. Also, I have list my tables and run select statements do ensure everything is fine.

Comment: @phoet I have check the columns and it appears that there is no such column as security_user_id - does this mean that I should add this column in my table in order to make relationship working or Rails is handling this somehow?